# Spring JDBC `SimpleJdbcCall` with BLOB outputs, only returns 8000 bytes

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jtds

I have attempted to use a stored procedure to extract a PDF stored as a BLOB in a SQL Server database. A bit similar to the following:

```
SimpleJdbcCall sp = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate())
        .withSchemaName("dbo")
        .withProcedureName("sp_find_doc")
        .declareParameters(
                new SqlParameter("DocID", java.sql.Types.BIGINT),
                new SqlOutParameter("DocBLOB", java.sql.Types.BLOB));

SqlParameterSource args = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("ID", 1L);
Map<String, Object> map = sp.execute(args);
```

The stored procedure defines the output as `varbinary(max)`, so it should support pretty large outputs. However, the PDF is corrupted. Examining more closely, I can see that the object returned by the `execute` method to the map is truncated to 8000 bytes.

8000 bytes is a basic `varbinary` (without the `max`), so I'm guessing that some component is failing to specify the output type correctly. Or perhaps the `execute` method is only reading off the first 8000 bytes?

Is there something missing from my code above to ensure that Spring JDBC defines the correct types and maps all the bytes in the BLOB?

Note that I have also tried specifying `useLOBs=false` on the database URL and `LONGVARBINARY` for the outputs, but again, 8000 bytes was the limit to the arrays returned.

FYI - I'm using SQL Server 2014, jTDS 1.3.1 and Spring Boot 1.3.1 (Spring JDBC 4.2.3).

**Workaround**

Note that I have implemented a workaround of rewriting the stored procedure to return a result set rather than output parameters. This way, I can use `rs.getBlob("DocBLOB")`, which works nicely.

But of course I would be interested to find out whether there is a correct/better way to execute stored procedures which return BLOBs in output parameters.

Comment: Are you specifying a version of the TDS protocol in your configuration for that connection? Reports like [this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/513/) suggest that older protocol versions (circa SQL Server 2000) will sometimes truncate long "things" at 4000 or 8000 characters/bytes depending on the circumstances.

Comment: I'm not specifying a version, so according to the jTDS docs, it should be defaulting to 8.0. I don't see any options for higher versions. It does seem that jTDS hasn't updated for a while though. I'm able to get 80k+ objects back from result sets, but it's just these stored procedure output params that seem to limit things to 8k.

Comment: Have you tried the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver instead?

Comment: I'm a bit tempted to see if it's any good these days ... last time I tried, it couldn't handle named pipes, which prevented me using it in some of our dev environments.